# Algorand and indexer nodes not starting when attempting to start Algorand Sandbox in Ubuntu 22

Tags: ubuntu, algorand

I am attempting to set up and run the Algorand Sandbox in Ubuntu 22 following instructions from https://developer.algorand.org/tutorials/create-and-test-smart-contracts-using-python/. I installed docker composer as required but when I attempt to run

```
./sandbox/sandbox up
```

I get the error

```
            Starting default sandbox: release
            see sandbox.log for detailed progress, or use -v.
            * docker containers started!
            * waiting for services to initialize.
            
            the following did not start:
            * algorand node
            * indexer node
            
            One or more services failed to start.
```

Is there a step I missed?

Comment: See https://forum.algorand.org/t/algorand-and-indexer-nodes-not-starting-when-attempting-to-start-algorand-sandbox-in-ubuntu-22/7659

Answer (score 0):

make sure to follow these steps for docker exactly: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/wsl/

Afterwards, run ./sandbox reset on Ubuntu

That worked for me